# How to getlcell.label.text value of uitableview cell in a string

Tags: uitableview, checkbox

I am making an app in which i am using tableview and in each table cell i am using checkboxes. now i am stuck in this place that when checkbox is checked i want to get value of that table-cell. like i am showing messages id in table cell i want to get messages_Id  of that cells whose checkboxes are checked. means if select 1 checkbox its message id is store in NSString and if i select 2 checkboxes then 2 messages of these checkboxes are store in string how it can be done.below is my sample code of tableview and check boxes action

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
   __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){

    }
     __block NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    cell.titlename.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];


    tocity.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"toCity"];
    fromcity.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"fromCity"];
   date.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageDate"];
    time.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageTime"];
    [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];






    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {


        [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]// here i am setting image
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    return cell;

}
```

and below is my check button code

```
-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblvie];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblvie indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        self.titleLabel.text=@"";

    }
    else {
        [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         self.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld selected",(long)sender.tag+1];
    }
    [self.tblvie reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

and i want to get value of these checked boxes in this button

```
- (IBAction)menubtun:(id)sender {

}
```

Comment: what is your **messages_Id** array name

Comment: @MishalAwan put a custom delegate from custom cell and there by u can get whole info of cell

Comment: yeah i done it but how to get value of checkboxes checked value ?

Comment: only issue i am facing that how to get values of checked checkboxes

Comment: comment below my answer .. or else i don't get notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67076/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-shan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there if want the cell info of selected cell, just handle the action method of `tickButton` in custom cell it self not in controller use below code define a protocol and define a delegate see the below code

in `tablecellTableViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class tablecellTableViewCell;

@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)checkBoxButtonSelected:(tablecellTableViewCell *)cell; //this is the custom delegate method
@end



@interface tablecellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImageView; //i changed the name for conventions 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tickButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel; //valuedate
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;


@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CustomCellDelegate> cellDelegate; //decleare a delegate hear

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font withString:(NSString *)title;

@end
```

and in `tablecellTableViewCell.m` all code is same but u have to connect a action to `tickButton` for example

```
 #import "tablecellTableViewCell.h"

 @implementation tablecellTableViewCell
 //@synthesize button,image;  
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if(self)
   {

   }
   return self;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   // Initialization code
   [super awakeFromNib];
   [self setUp];
}

//...same code of yours no need to change just a action method of tick button is added extra

//in this call a delegate method by passing the entire cell itself
- (IBAction)checkButtonAction:(id)sender
 {
   if([self.cellDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(checkBoxButtonSelected:)])
   {
       [self.cellDelegate checkBoxButtonSelected:self];//hear u are passing the enire cell to Fbinbox..controller
   }
 }
```

in the controller class  `.h file`

```
//..same code just confirm to protocol 
 @interface inboxViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,CustomCellDelegate> //confirm to protocol
{
   int checkBoxesCount;
}
```

in `.m file`

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)
    {

    }
    __block NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    cell.activityIndicatorView.hidden = NO;
    [cell.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    if([[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
   cell.messageLabel.text = [[self.inboxmessagesarray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"toCity"];
   cell.cellDelegate      = self;//add this one line

   //... rest same code but comment the action method of tick button

   //..hear in the last 
   cell.tickButton.tag = indexPath.row;
   // [cell.tickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //comemnt this line this tickbutton   action is in custom cell


 }

 //now define custom delegate method 
 - (void)checkBoxButtonSelected:(tablecellTableViewCell *)cell //in this cell contains every thing including message and all 
 {
   //hear u are getting the entire cell
   //now u can get the all info stored in this cell
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.activitiesTableView_ indexPathForCell:cell];

   if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
     [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     //....other stuff's
     //cell.textLabel.text;
     //..all info present in the cell
   }
   else
   {
     [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     //..do other stuff
     NSString *selectedMessage = cell.messageLabel.text;
     //cell.textLabel.text;
     //..all info present in the cell
     NSLog(@"SELECTED MESSAGE->%@",selectedMessage);

  }
  [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: let me check then will tell u

Comment: if i select two checkboxes then ?

Comment: means i have to store every checked checkbox message id in a string

Comment: use an array just add to it if deselect means just remove it

Comment: i am trying will let u know

Comment: @selector(checkBoxButtonSelected:)]) what is this mwthod checkBoxButtonSelected?

Comment: it is the delegate method u have to define it in controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67081/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-shan).